# .bash_profile not reflecting change in location of php

Tags: php, bash, ampps

I just ran the recent update for OSX, and when I restarted my bash_profile was no longer recognizing my new PATH for php.

If I `which php` I get `/usr/bin/php`

But in my ~/.bash_profile I have `export PATH=/Applications/AMPPS/php-5.4/bin/php:$PATH`

If I save and source it, I get the same thing for `which php`

I have scoured the other forums, I do not have a ~/.profile or a ~/.bashrc file, so if my research is correct, it should be reading from .bash_profile.

Am I wrong in my assumption? This is really annoying, I just want my other version of php back to default.

Any help is very much appreciated.

Edit: the result of `echo $PATH` is

`/Applications/AMPPS/php-5.4/bin/php:/Applications/AMPPS/php-5.6/bin/php:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin`

Comment: Can you add the result of `echo $PATH`?

Comment: Your path has two copies of AMPPS/php-5.4, it's probably not related but you'll want to look into it.

Comment: Where would I look to see where the other path is coming from? The bash_profile only has the single line, which is the PATH.

Comment: If I source the bash_profile over, it keeps appending to PATH when I do echo $PATH, is that normal? Because now there's 3.

Comment: That makes sense, every time you source it, you're rerunning that code which will be prepending /AMPPS/... to your PATH variable (which already has added it).

Comment: Oh I was under the assumption that was sort of a 'reload' command or something. Is there any way to clear that variable to resource it only once?

Answer (score 0):

Paths need to be your **path to** the application.  If the executable php is at `/Applications/AMPPS/php-5.4/bin/php`
your PATH needs to be set to `/Applications/AMPPS/php-5.4/bin`